# Kinect mechanics: where do lost frames go? - a framerate affair

Tags: c#, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am having some hard time in understanding what really happens when kinect is used with slow computers or heavy framewise computations are required.

Let us consider the [C# sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131029.aspx) for recovering depth.

The runtime dynamics is driven by the `DepthFrameReady` event. The function `DepthImageReady` hereby reported is invoked when such event is triggered.

```
 private void DepthImageReady(object sender, DepthImageFrameReadyEventArgs e)
 {
    using (DepthImageFrame depthFrame = e.OpenDepthImageFrame())
    {
        if (depthFrame != null)
        {
           depthFrame.CopyDepthImagePixelDataTo(this.depthPixels);

           //MY OPERATIONS BLABLABLA...
        } 
        else
        {
         // depthFrame is null because the request did not arrive in time
        }
    }
 }
```

My cross-correlated questions are:

- Is this function actually called for every frame?
- How come that `depthFrame` can be `Null`?
- What really happens if my operations take longer than the nominal inter-frame time (33ms)?
- Is there any buffer inside the kinect?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "Where do lost frames go?" To Tumbolia, of course.

Answer (score 1):

According to the tutorial here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131029.aspx#CS_Notify_Depth

According to that tutorial, the event is fired for every frame (i.e. enqueued in the event queue), however if you take too long processing the previous frame, you will find that when processing the next frame the `OpenDepthImageFrame()` method will return `null`, indicating that the frame data is no longer available.

Comment: that explains the line :

 if (depthFrame != null)

Answer (score 0):

I think the mechanic is that it is just a buffer
The event (your start of the image retrieval) is raised when it has data.
As the data is not stored (it doesnt queue), its erased and written again for each new thread that is launched. So therefore there is the check with !=null

They might in the background raise threads, with a pointer pointing to the new buffer area, then by changing the buffer pointer (a new frame loads arives complete) they only swap the pointers, effectively resulting in a null pointer for old thread and old data while the new thread has the new data (data stays as long as that thread is alive). but threads that have been queued then dont contain data (pointer was swapped), and so to your app then the tread queue wont build up. and old threads image data will not queue up either.

Well that is how i think it works, but i dont have their source code, no one has.